# How can I connect to MSSQL Express with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server

I have a application -created from visual studio 2010 - and I have a dedicated server . The server's operating system is windows server 2003. My web application is working on Visual Studio's localhost and my IIS localhost. But when I published it to server it gives me this error.

```
Login failed for user 'sa'. 


Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'sa'.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'sa'.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +5066458
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning() +234
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +2275
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK) +35
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnection owningObject) +183
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, TimeoutTimer timeout) +239
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +195
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +232
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection) +185
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options) +33
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject) +524
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject) +66
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject) +479
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) +108
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +126
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +125
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +123
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +319
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet) +94
   BerksanWebSite.Default2.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\tekizer\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\BerksanWebSite\BerksanWebSite\Default2.aspx.cs:94
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +91
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +74
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2207

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1022
```

Here is my connectionstring tag in web.config file

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="websitesiConnectionString" connectionString="Server=xx.xxx.xxx.xxx; Database=websitesi;User ID=xxxx;Password=xxxxxx;"/>

  </connectionStrings>
```

I have created a class file to call connection string for c# codes . So here is my c# connection variables in c# class.

```
private static string connectionstring_ = "Server=xx.xxx.xxx.xxx; Database=websitesi;User ID=xxxx;Password=xxxxxx;";
```

I am calling this from my c# pages to connect my database on dedicated server.

```
SqlConnection baglanti = new SqlConnection(berksanproje.connectionstring);
if(baglanti.State!=ConnectionState.Open)
{
baglanti.Open();
}
```

In my dedicated server's ASP.NET web application properties 
ASP.NET version 4.0.30319
when I click edit configuration and click general tab it gives :

```
LocalSqlServer : Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=berksanwebsitesi;Integrated Security=True;

websitesiConnectionString : Server=xx.xxx.xxx.xxx; Database=websitesi;User ID=xxxx;Password=xxxxxx;
```

I can connect to my database from my computer with remote connection via MSSQL . But I can not connect with my aspx page after I published. Is there any way to connect my database with asp.net

Note: I don't write anywhere to connect with user sa. I don't use it.

Comment: Looks like your ASP page tries to connect via sql server authentication (user name + password) while from your computer you connect via windows authentication (integrated security). So, is the SQL Server configured to be able to use sql server authentication (i.e. "mixed mode")? http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms144284.aspx -- also, if you have a named instance, you probably need to specify that (`Server=xx.xxx.xxx.xx\InstanceName`)

Comment: Yes . I can connect from my computer with IP . 1433 port is open

Comment: Is SQL server running in the services??

Comment: Yes. -I wrote on top - . It works on my computer via visual studio's localhost. Database is on dedicated server .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed windows server 2008 to my dedicated server . Then after installing .NET Framework 4.0 and MSSQL Server 2008 R2 Express with Management studio my system is working.

Answer (score -1):

It seems you have to use windows authentification or you don't have the `sa` user,

I assume that you connect using windows authentification , so change all connection strings like this :

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;
```

See this [link](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) for more details, maybe the windows authentification is not needed for your case so check the link and find the connection string suitable for you

Comment: Do you have a Sql server 'sa' user? when you connect to your sql server instance , do u use windows authentification??

Comment: I have sa user . But i didn't use it anywhere. When i try to use sa nothing changes in there. I don't know how can i solve this problem

Comment: @enderariç can u connect using sql server management studio to your sql server using the user `sa`???

Comment: yes i can connect wih sql server management studio using user sa

Comment: i suggest to replace ALL connection string like this `Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=websitesi;
User ID=sa;Password=yourpassword;` . I assume that your password is **yourpassword**

Comment: ok, create a text file and change its extension with `.udl` ( .txt => .udl) , then you can test the connection to your database.After working, give me please all detail about the connection so we can deduce the connection string